# String comparison in Ruby not returning correct test

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to test for a palindrome but this code never returns true in the test.

```
for a in (0..(myString.length/2)) do
  if (myString[a] == myString[myString.length-a+1])
    p = true
  else
    p = false
  end
end
```

What am i missing?

I have already tried different equalities and string methods already.

thanks

Comment: Because you never actually `return` anything...

Comment: so how would you change the code to return something?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? I would start by printing the indices `a` and `myString.length-a+1` withing the loop to check if they are correct.

Comment: (`myString == myString.reverse`)

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in code:

First, the index of the second character in the comparison is not calculated correctly. Let's take the first iteration as an example. In the first iteration, `a` will be `0`. That means the second character's position will be calculated to (imagine the string `racecar`) `7-0+1 = 8` which would be out of bounds of the string. Instead, the last character in the string has the index `6`, because the index starts counting at `0`.

This can be fixed by calculating the second index like this: `myString.length -a-1`

The second issue is that you do not return immediately when two characters aren't matching. Imagine the string `abbc`. In the first iteration, `a` and `c` would be compared and `p` would be set to `false`. But in the next iteration `b` and `b` are compared and `p` would be changed to `true`, although, the first iteration already proved that the string is not a palindrome.

I suggest changing the implementation to:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  0.upto(string.length / 2 - 1).all? { |i| string[i] == string[-i - 1] }
end

palindrome?('racecar')
#=> true

palindrome?('foobar')
#=> false
```

See docs for [`Integer#upto`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-upto) and [`Array#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-all-3F) and how [`String#[]` behaves with negative indexes](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#class-String-label-String+Slices).

Comment: You can use `all?` to get rid of the explicit `return` statements.

Comment: @Stefan. Thank you, that is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `+` where you need a `-`.

```rb
if (myString[a] == myString[myString.length-a+1]) #your code
if (myString[a] == myString[myString.length-a-1]) #updated code with "a-1" instead of "a+1"
if (myString[a] == myString[-(a+1)]) #alternative solution: Negative indexes would be my prefered way to solve this
```

You assigned local variable p instead of calling `Kernel#p` method

```rb
p = true #your code
p "true" #updated code converted to `p` method
```

Fully Updated Code

```rb
myString = "abba"

for a in (0..(myString.length/2)) do
  if (myString[a] == myString[-(a+1)])
    p "true"
  else
    p "false"
  end
end

=begin
code outputs:
true
true
true
=end
```

Comment: thanks. Updated code:

myString = gets.chomp
pal = true

for a in (0..(myString.length/2)) do
  if (myString[a] == myString[-(a+1)])
    pal = true
  else
    pal = false
    break
  end
end

if pal
  puts "this is a palindrome"
else puts "this is not a palindrome"
end

Comment: Unrelated, but you should avoid `for` in Ruby. [It's weird](http://graysoftinc.com/early-steps/the-evils-of-the-for-loop). Prefer `(0..(myString.length/2)).each do |a| ... end` instead. In this case, `any?` is a perfect fit.

Comment: Additionally while this prints the Strings "true" or "false" to STDOUT N times the actual return value will always be a `Range` which will not indicate if the original String is a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 0):

**my expected code:**

```
def is_palindrome(myString)
  for a in 0..(myString.length/2) do
    if myString[a] != myString[myString.length-a-1]
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

FOr testing add this:
**puts is_palindrome("racecar")**

Comment: You can replace this for loop an explicit returns with just an `any?`: `(0..(myString.length/2)).any? { |a| myString[a] != myString[myString.length-a-1] }`